# IPv4 link-local address with NetworkManager

Tags: networking, dhcp, raspberry-pi-os-buster, networkmanager

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 that is running Buster/32bit (upgrading the OS is currently not an option).

The Raspberry Pi runs in headless mode, with `ssh` and `vnc` enabled.

In order to find the machine in the network, Avahi is installed (so I should be able to connect to it via `mypi.local`).

As I want to be able to connect to my uni's WiFi network (eduroam; WAP2/MSCHAP), i figured that the default `dhcpcd` network daemon is not sufficient, and I installed `NetworkManager` instead.

However, the typical connectivity of the Raspberry Pi is a wired-connection, either in a larger network (with DHCP) or connecting it directly to a laptop (link-local).

Now, everything works as expected if I hook up the Raspberry Pi to my DHCP-enabled network.

However, I *cannot* figure out how to get link-local connections working.

Checking zeroconf announcements with my trusted avahi-discover, I noticed that in the latter case the Pi announces itself via some IPv6 address, but not via an IPv4 address.

Since I guess that this is the actual problem, I try to convince NetworkManager to fall-back to link-local IPv4 addresses, if DHCP fails.
Unfortunately I have no idea, how.

I read in /usr/share/doc/network-manager/NEWS.gz for NetworkManger-1.2:

> Native IPv4 link-local addressing configuration based on systemd network library is now used instead.

So I guess I must configure "systemd network", which (I think) is done via `/etc/systemd/network/`.
Note, that `systemd-networkd` is not running/activated!

Anyhow, I've created a file `/etc/systemd/network/98-mypi.network`, with the following content (pilfered from some systemd unit-tests):

```ini
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=yes
IPv6AcceptRA=no
IPv4LLStartAddress=169.254.133.11
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to do anything useful.

Occasionally I now see the Raspberry Pi announcing itself via ZeroConf, but using the IPv4-address it got assigned from the DHCP-server, the last time it connected to that.

Since the peer machine (my laptop) is not in that network, i stlil cannot reach the Pi (also I would like to not use the DHCP-address on the link-local connection - imagine I configure my double-ethernet desktop to be connected to both the DHCP-network and the Pi (the latter via link-local).

**So:**

How can I convince NetworkManager to configure the `eth0` interface to fall-back to a proper IPv4 link-local address, if DHCP fails?

(This all worked with `dhcpcd`, but due to the WiFi handling, I really want use NetworkManager)

Comment: while it's fine if you downvote my question if you find it inappropriate, it would be *great* if you could comment on why you think so. (so I can improve future questions to meet the standards)

Answer (score 0):

What version of systemd? You can use:

```
systemctl --version
```

I think you need >= 252

You can use *systemctl status systemd-networkd* to check for any errors. If your version isn't right you might see an issue like *Unknown key name 'IPv4LLStartAddress' in section 'Network', ignoring.*

The feature is added here
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/23927
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/c1dd250f18d96d31608cbabfb32c8e5a4c36fd41

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/24019
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/24019/files/72c747e6d10637c0844e7c239a47bd5e6d42763c